# Designs and practices to guard against erroneous null entries from database

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, database-design, patterns-and-practices, null

One part of my program fetches data from many tables and columns in my database for processing. Some of the columns might be `null`, but in the current processing context that is an error.

This should "theoretically" not happen, so if it does it points to bad data or a bug in the code. The errors have different severities, depending which field is `null`; i.e. for some fields the processing should be stopped and somebody notified, for others the processing should be allowed to continue and just notify somebody.

**Are there any good architecture or design principles to handle the rare but possible `null` entries?**

The solutions should be possible to implement with Java but I didn't use the tag because I think the problem is somewhat language-agnostic.

---

Some thoughts that I had myself:

#### Using NOT NULL

Easiest would be to use a NOT NULL constraint in the database.

But what if the original inserting of the data is more important that this later processing step? So in case the insert would put a `null` into the table (either because of bugs or maybe even some valid reason), I wouldn't want the insert to fail. Let's say that many more parts of the program depend on the inserted data, but not on this particular column. So I would rather risk the error in the current processing step instead of the insert step. That's why I don't want to use a NOT NULL constraint.

#### Naively depending on NullPointerException

I could just use the data as if I expect it to be always there (and that should really be the case), and catch resulting NPEs at an appropriate level (e.g. so that the processing of the current entry stops but not the whole processing progress). This is the "fail fast" principle and I often prefer it. If it is a bug at least I get a logged NPE.

But then I lose the ability to differentiate between various kinds of missing data. E.g. for some missing data I could leave it out, but for others the processing should be stopped and an admin notified.

#### Checking for `null` before each access and throwing custom exceptions

Custom exceptions would let me decide the correct action based on the exception, so this seems like the way to go.

But what if I forget to check it somewhere? Also I then clutter my code with null checks which are never or rarely expected (and so definitely not part of the business logic flow).

If I choose to go this way, what patterns are best suited for the approach?

---

Any thoughts and comments on my approaches are welcomed. Also better solutions of any kind (patterns, principles, better architecture of my code or models etc.).

**Edit:**

There is another constraint, in that i am using an ORM to do the mapping from DB to persistence object, so doing null checks on that level would not work (as the same objects are used in parts where the null does not do any harm). I added this because the answers provided so far both mentioned this option.

Comment: "Some of the columns might be null, but in the current processing context that is an error. ... in case the insert would put a null into the table, I wouldn't want the insert to fail. "  Those two requirements are contradictory. It's **impossible** to find a solution until you relax one of the two conditions.

Comment: @KilianFoth Well, my relaxation is that the error in the "current processing" context is less severe than when inserting. So I accept rare processing errors, but I want to have a good robust design to handle them. That's why NOT NULL, which would otherwise be a good solution, is not possible here.

Comment: If you go about accepting so many errors, the originators of that errors will never correct them. If their messy insert statements succeed, what incentive do they ever have to fix things up? Do you consider robust not failing but accepting bad data?

Comment: @user61852 I'm explicitly not accepting the errors but want to handle them gracefully. Swallowing null pointers is out of the question. Also, what if my part is really objectively (as defined by the business) less important than many other parts which require the insert to succeed but don't require this particular field to be set? The inserts originate not from a user entry where I could force them to add the value, but from other code where omission is most likely a bug (but not important enough to break the insert).

Comment: Marking them as NOT NULL in the database would be the best solution, if a column is nullable, then the code will need to handle the case when it is, even if it is not expected because the storage mechanism allows it.

Comment: Looks like a problem which would not exist when using strong & static type system.

Comment: @SargeBorsch is that a statement about Java or about my design? If the latter, what might be a better approach?

Comment: @KilianFoth: I don't think they're contradictory. Data required by OP's process may be unknown at entry time, so it's to be expected that some columns might be null. Those values should be supplied during some upstream process, so by the time they arrive in OP's bailiwick everything is coherent. It sounds like there may be no clear indication that the data is complete, so OP has to deal with the incomplete stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would put the null checks in your mapping code, where you build your object from the result set. That puts the checking in one place, and won't allow your code to get halfway through processing a record before hitting an error. Depending on how your application flow works, you might want to perform the mapping of all the results as a pre-processing step instead of mapping and processing each record one at a time.

If you're using an ORM then you'll have to perform all your null checks before processing each record. I'd recommend a `recordIsValid(recordData)`-type method, that way you can (again) keep all the null-checking and other validation logic in one place. I definitely wouldn't intermingle the null checks with the rest of your processing logic.

Comment: Thank you, that's good insight! I am indeed using an ORM, so checks on that level will not work. But I have also some mapping to real domain objects from the persistence objects. I will check whether doing the mapping and validating in a preprocessing step would be possible.

Comment: And if you switch your ORM, then what then? Better to defend this at source (see Doc Brown's answer).

Comment: @RobbieDee: Shouldn't matter. If you have to rewrite the mapping code then either the null checks are in there and you modify them as part of the rewrite, or you've got a separate method that performs the null checks on your business objects, so there's no rewrite needed. And as Doc Brown implies, sometimes it's important to notice that data is missing instead of glossing over that fact with a default value.

Comment: That should happen further up in the ETL flow. You still risk duplicating effort this way.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like inserting a null is an error but you are afraid to enforce this error on insertion because you don't want to lose data. However, if a field shouldn't be null but is, *you are losing data*. Therefore the best solution is to ensure that null fields are not erroneously getting saved in the first place.

To this end, enforce that the data is correct in the one authoritative, permanent repository for that data, the database. Do so by adding not null constraints. Then your code might fail but these failures immediately notify you of bugs, allowing you to correct issues that are already causing you to lose data. Now that you are easily able to identify bugs, *test your code* and test it twice. You'll be able to correct bugs leading to data loss and in the process, greatly simplify downstream processing of the data because you won't need to worry about nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that your solution is the right way to do it, and you've phrased it concisely. Constraints outside my influence might make it difficult or impossible (e.g. unavailable resources for testing or for making existing code automatically testable), but I definitely should double check if this solution can work before trying out other ways. In my original thinking I maybe assumed too quickly that I cannot fix the problem at the source.

Comment: @jhyot Okay. It's frustrating when you can't do things the clean way. Hopefully my answer is at least useful to others who have similar problems but who are able to attack the root cause instead of clean up the mess after the fact.

Answer (score 5):

In regard to this sentence in the question:

> This should "theoretically" not happen, so if it does it points to bad data or a bug in the code.

I have always appreciated this quote (courtesy of [this article](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/08/what-to-know-before-debating-type-systems.html)):

> I find it amusing when novice programmers believe their main job is preventing programs from crashing. I imagine this spectacular failure argument wouldn't be so appealing to such a programmer. More experienced programmers realize that correct code is great, code that crashes could use improvement, but incorrect code that doesn't crash is a horrible nightmare.

Basically: it sounds like you are endorsing [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), "be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept". While great in theory, **in practice this "robustness principle" leads to software that is *not* robust**, at least in the long term -- and sometimes in the short term as well. (Compare Eric Allman's paper [The Robustness Principle Reconsidered](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1999945), which is a very thorough treatment of the subject, albeit mostly focused on network protocol use cases.)

If you have programs that are incorrectly inserting data into your database, those programs are **broken** and need to be **fixed**. Papering over the problem only allows it to continue to get worse; this is the software engineering equivalent of [*enabling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling) an addict to continue their addiction.

Pragmatically speaking, though, sometimes you do need to enable "broken" behavior to continue, at least temporarily, especially as part of a seamless transition from a lax, broken state to a strict, correct state. In that case, you want to find a way to **allow the incorrect insertions to succeed, but still allow the "canonical" data store to always be in a correct state**. There are various ways to do this:

- Use a database trigger to convert malformed inserts into correct inserts, e.g. by replacing missing/null values with defaults
- Have the incorrect programs insert into a separate database table that is allowed to be "incorrect", and have a separate scheduled process or other mechanism that moves corrected data from that table into the canonical data store
- Use query-side filtering (e.g. a view) to ensure that the data retrieved from the database is always in a correct state, even if the data at rest is not

One way to sidestep all of these issues is to **insert an API layer that you control** between programs that issue writes and the actual database.

It sounds like part of your problem is that you don't even know all the places that are generating incorrect writes -- or that there are simply too many of them for you to update. That's a scary state to be in, but it should never have been allowed to arise in the first place.

As soon as you get more than a handful of systems that are allowed to modify data in a canonical production data store you are going to be in trouble: there is no way to centrally maintain *anything* about that database. Better would be to allow as few processes as possible to issue writes, and use those as "gatekeepers" that can preprocess the data before inserting as necessary. The exact mechanism for this really depends on your specific architecture.

Comment: "If you have programs that are incorrectly inserting data into your database, those programs are broken and need to be fixed." that's great in theory as well, but the reality is they'll still be adding records while some committee continues to debate over whether to use "NA" or "None".

Comment: @JeffO: No committee should be debating whether to *store* "NA", "None", NULL, or something else in the database. Non-technical stakeholders have a stake in what data comes *out* of the database and how it is used, but not in the internal representation.

Comment: @DanielPryden: At my last job, we had an Architecture Review Board (with a DBA sub-committee) that would review cross-domain technical changes. Very technical, but they only met every two weeks and if you didn't provide enough detail for them they'd defer a decision until you did...at a subsequent meeting. Most non-trivial system changes that didn't consist of adding functionality through new code would routinely take a month or so.

Comment: @DanielPryden - I've sat in meetings with upper-management debating on text box labels. You could argue that this has nothing to do with what you're going to name it in the application or the database, but it does.

Comment: In response to comments about getting additional approvals for changes of this kind: my point about the values being "incorrect" presupposes that the allowable values are already documented somewhere -- that's why the OP says that these values should be considered a bug. If the schema of the database is specified to allow a value, then that value is not a bug. The point is that if you have data that doesn't match your schema, then something is broken: your priority should be to make the data and the schema match. Depending on the team, that may involve changing the data, the schema, or both.

Answer (score 2):

"**Are there any good architecture or design principles to handle the rare but possible null entries?**"

Simple answer - yes.

**[ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)**

Carry out some up front processing to ensure the data is of sufficient quality to go into the database. Anything in the drop file should be reported back and any clean data can be loaded into the database.

As someone who has been both poacher (dev) and game keeper (DBA), I know from bitter experience that 3rd parties simply will not resolve their data issues unless they're forced to. Constantly bending over backwards and massaging data through sets a dangerous precedent.

**Mart/Repository**

In this scenario, raw data is pushed into the repository DB and then a sanitised version is pushed to the mart DB which applications then have access to.

**Default values**

If you can apply sensible default values to columns then you should although this can involve some work if this is an existing database.

**Fail early**

It is tempting to simply address data issues at the gateway to the application, report suite, interface etc. I'd strongly advise you not to solely rely on this. If you hook in some other widget to the DB you'll potentially be faced with the same problems again. Address the data quality issues.

Comment: +1 This is what I would do, collect all data and create a valid data set for your application to process.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your use case allows to replace NULL safely by a good default value, you can do the conversion in the `SELECT` Sql statements using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`. So instead of

```
 SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable
```

one can write

```
 SELECT ISNULL(MyColumn,DefaultValueForMyColumn) FROM MyTable
```

Of course, that will only work when the ORM allows to manipulate the select statements directly, or provide changeable templates for the generation. One should make sure that no "real" errors are masked this way, so apply it only if replacing by a default value is exactly what you want in case of NULL.

If you are able to change the database and the schema, and your db system supports this, you may consider to add a default value clause to the specific columns, as suggested by @RobbieDee. However, this will also require to modify the existing data in the database to remove any previously inserted NULL values, and it will remove the ability to distinguish between correct and incomplete import data afterwards.

From my own experience, I know that using ISNULL can work surprisingly well - in the past I had to maintain a legacy application where the original devs had forgotten to add NOT NULL constraints to lots of columns, and we could not easily add those constraints later for some reasons. But in 99% of all cases, 0 as default for number columns and the empty string as default for a text columns was fully acceptable.

Comment: Whilst this works, you can end up having to duplicate the defensive code for each SELECT. A far better approach is to define a default value for a column when a NULL is inserted although this may not be possible/desirable for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @RobbieDee: thanks for that remark, I changed my answer accordingly. However, if this is "far better" is debatable. When the CRUD code is in one place, duplicate defensive code may not be much of a problem. And if it is not, there is already some code duplication beforehand.

Comment: Simple CRUD operations are of course the ideal. But in the real world, systems often have complex UI views, user generated data wizards, reports etc etc. But as you've pointed out, default values need to be there from the ground up or at least require some initial conversion effort. What you've described could be preferable in a brownfield development.

Comment: Best answer. New applications usually add some new data which may be outside your control. Erroneous NULLs usually come from importing legacy data into redesigned databases. Constraints are turned off for this to allow it to complete in a few hours instead of several days. "The big fail" often comes when the DBAs try to re-enable the constraints. Since it was never planned for, management often balks at the weeks of work often required to fix the bad data, so it remains. All apps should gracefully handle NULLs by inserting defaults and reporting or prompting for the missing data otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is presuming an answer that couples business rules with database technical details.

> This should "theoretically" not happen, so if it does it points to bad data or a bug in the code. The errors have different severities, depending which field is null; i.e. for some fields the processing should be stopped and somebody notified, for others the processing should be allowed to continue and just notify somebody.

This is all business rules. The business rules do not care about null per-se. For all it knows the database could have null, 9999, "BOO!" ... It is just another value. That, in a RDBMS, null has interesting properties and unique uses is moot.

The only thing that matters is what "null-ness" means for the given business object(s)...

> Are there any good architecture or design principles to handle the rare but possible null entries?

Yes.

- Put business rules in classes.
- The transliteration should be in an appropriate code layer decoupling the business classes and data store. If you can't put it in the ORM code at least don't put it in the database.
- Make the database dumb as possible, no business rules here. *Even innocuous things like defaulting a value will bite you*. Been there.
- Validate data going to and coming from the database. And of course this is done w/in the context of the business objects.

---

**Throwing an exception upon data retrieval** does not make sense.

The question is **"should I store 'bad' data"?** It depends:

- *Bad data might be used* - Never save invalid objects, or object composites. Complex data/business relationships all over the place. Users can do any function at any given time, possibly using that business entity in a number of contexts. The effect (if any) of bad data, at the time it is saved, is not known because it is highly dependent on future use. There is no unified/single process of that data.
- *Cannot progress if there is bad data* - Allow saving of bad data. However the next step in a process cannot continue until everything is valid. For example doing one's income taxes. When retrieved from the database the software points out the errors and it cannot be submitted to the IRS without validity checking.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle nulls, so we'll move on from the database layer up to the application layer.

---

**Database layer**

You can *forbid nulls*; although here it is impractical.

You can *configure a default* on a per column basis:

- it requires that the column be *absent* from the `insert`, so does not cover explicit null insertion
- it prevents the detection from rows where the `insert` erroneously missed this column

You can *configure a trigger*, so that upon insertion the missing values are automatically computed:

- it requires that the necessary information to perform this computation be present
- it will slow down the `insert`

---

**Query layer**

You can *skip rows* where an inconvenient `null` is present:

- it simplifies the main logic
- it prevents detecting the "bad rows", so another process would be needed to check on them
- it requires that each query be instrumented

You can *provide a default value* in the query:

- it simplifies the main logic
- it prevents detecting the "bad rows", so another process would be needed to check on them
- it requires that each query be instrumented

*Note: instrumenting each query is not necessarily an issue if you have some automated way of generating them.*

---

**Application layer**

You can *pre-check* the table for forbidden `null`:

- it simplifies the main logic
- it improves the time-to-failure
- it requires keeping the pre-check and application logic consistent

You can *interrupt the processing* when encountering a forbidden `null`:

- it avoids duplicating the knowledge of which columns can be `null` and which cannot
- it is still relatively simple (just a check + return/throw)
- it requires that your process be resumable (if you already sent an e-mail, don't want to send it twice, or a hundred times!)

You can *skip the row* when encountering a forbidden `null`:

- it avoids duplicating the knowledge of which columns can be `null` and which cannot
- it is still relatively simple (just a check + return/throw)
- it does not require that your process be resumable

You can *send a notification* when encountering a forbidden `null`, either one at a time or by batch, which is complimentary to the other ways presented above. What matters most however is "what then?", most notably, if you expect the row to be patched and in need of being re-processed you may need to ensure that you have some way to distinguish already processed rows from rows in need of being re-processed.

---

Given your situation, I would handle the situation at the application and combine either:

- *interrupt* and *notify*
- *skip* and *notify*

I would tend toward just *skipping* if possible to somehow guarantee a modicum of progress, especially if the processing can take time.

If you do not need to re-process the skipped rows, then simply logging them should be sufficient and an e-mail sent at the end of process with the number of skipped rows will be an apt notification.

Otherwise, I would use a side-table for the rows to be fixed (and re-processed). This side-table may either be a simple reference (without foreign key) or a full-blown copy: the latter, even if more expensive, is necessary if you do not have the time to address the `null` before having to cleanup the main data.

Answer (score -1):

Nulls can be handled in the translation or mapping of database types to language types.  For example in C#, here's a generic method that handles null for you for any type:

```
public static T Convert<T>(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return (T) obj;
        }

public static T Convert<T>(object obj, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (obj == DBNull.Value)
            {
                T t = defaultValue;
                return t;
            }

            return (T) obj;
        }
```

Or, if you want to perform action...

```
 public static T Convert<T>(object obj, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (obj == DBNull.Value)
            {
                //Send an Alert, we might want pass in the name
                //of column or other details as well
                SendNullAlert();
                //Set it to default so we can keep processing
                T t = defaultValue;
                return t;
            }

            return (T) obj;
        }
```

And then in the mapping, in this case to an object of type "Sample", we will handle null for any of the columns:

```
public class SampleMapper : MapperBase<Sample>
    {
        private const string Id = "Id";
        private const string Name = "Name";
        private const string DataValue = "DataValue";
        private const string Created = "Created";

        protected override Sample Map(IDataRecord record)
        {
            return new Sample(
                Utility.Convert<Int64>(record[Id]),
                Utility.Convert<String>(record[Name]),
                Utility.Convert<Int32>(record[DataValue]),
                Utility.Convert<DateTime>(record[Created])
                );
        }
    }
```

Finally, all the mapping classes can be automatically generated based on the SQL query or tables involved by looking at the SQL data types and translating them to the language specific data types.   This is what many ORMs do for you automatically.  Note that some database types may not have a direct mapping (Geo-spatial colunms etc.) and may need special handling.

Comment: If someone wants to post the equivalent Java version that would be great...

Comment: I think the example code is perfectly understandable also for Java developers. In my situation I already have an ORM in place, so don't need to implement one. But your answer only addresses default values for nulls, whereas in my case actually the much more important case is detecting a null and triggering an action (e.g. inform an admin about the erroneous data).

Comment: Ahhh, I will update my answer based on this.

Comment: Your edited code now has one default action for any null value (i.e. it is completely generic). That's very similar to my 2nd option in the original question, i.e. just throw on null and catch it somewhere. But as stated there I need to differentiate the actions based on which value is missing.